# gulp-ruby-sass plugin not caching Sass files

Tags: caching, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

How to cache Sass files with [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass)? It seems that it should be a default option, but that’s not happening. I must be missing something.

While the `watch` task runs, for every time I change something in *app/styles/main.scss*, `gulp-ruby-sass` will compile Bootstrap's Sass again unnecessarily, taking up around **4-5 extra seconds**.

My *app/styles/main.scss* file looks like this:

```
// MY PROJECT DEFAULTS
@import “my_project/variables";

// bower:scss
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss";
// endbower

// ...
```

The *gulpfile.js* was generated on 2014-11-25 using *generator-gulp-webapp 0.1.0*, linked to the master branch from the git repo.

[See the gulpfile.js here](http://jsbin.com/qacudo/1/edit?js)

Styles function:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.rubySass({
      style: 'expanded',
      precision: 10
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'));
});
```

*.sass-cache* folder is being created, and its folders includes `main.scssc` as well as Bootstrap's partials.

**UPDATE**

So far I've found two solutions (not for caching though, but for faster compile time):

1) [gulp-ruby-sass version 1.0](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/tree/rw/1.0) (alpha), which is faster and works with source-maps. It seems that will soon be released. [Check this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/pull/137)

2) [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-sass) which uses C/C++ and it's very fast, but doesn't have some features.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you issue is related to https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/111. Although this issue is open still, i can't not confirm your issue when using `generator-gulp-webapp 0.3.0` (and `gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.1` with Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve))

`generator-gulp-webapp 0.3.0` ships with `gulp-sass` by default. After installing a gulp-webapp with Sass and Bootstrap i replace the `styles` task as follows:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return $.rubySass('app/styles/main.scss') 
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
   })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

After changing `main.scss` the `watch` task runs and outputs:

```
[BS] 1 file changed (main.css) 
[15:53:17] Finished 'styles' after 20 s
```

Now the content of `.sass-cache` folder look like that shown beneath:

```
/.sass-cache$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 6 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:48 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:40 721aed65acc825809156d020625072c6ea20be50
drwxrwxr-x 2 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:40 b311c6377fb599f57cc8c0d0c360c9b83a27e34b
drwxrwxr-x 2 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:40 d1eb2de86ef2be3a4571ad5415b5156c01618faf
drwxrwxr-x 2 bass bass 4096 Apr 13 15:53 e2b546d387a82bc59b03d84e84d775c05a23ac82
```

As far as a do understand only `e2b546d387a82bc59b03d84e84d775c05a23ac82` has been changed, which contains only a cached version of `main.scss`.